# Toast Immediately

Tags: android, multithreading, paint, toast

I would like to have a Toast Message appear while my app is downloading information but even if I put it before my code it doesn't appear until after the download has completed.  Putting my code in a separate thread causes many headaches but putting toast in a separate thread doesn't work either.  Is there anyway I can have this Toast message come up before this or am I just going to have to work through the headaches?

Comment: This title certainly caught my eye for all the wrong reasons.

Comment: I wish I could toast bread immediately too.  You are not alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be putting asynchronous downloads in a separate thread anyway, so as to not disable the main thread's UI. When you call a blocking I/O method, the UI will not respond.

Check out this documentation on [Handling Expensive Operation in the UI Thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#threading).

Comment: I know, but Java has a paintImmediatly method that you can use if you need to paint something even if the UI thread is being blocked.

Comment: @Mitchell: The problem is that if the UI thread blocks for too long (I believe 5 seconds), Android assumes that your app is frozen and displays the ANR dialog to the user.  You really don't want that.

Comment: I didn't know that was what was causing that.  So I guess the point is moot.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

As magaio already said you should use another thread for downloading stuff. My two cents:

- use progress dialog instead of Toast so User can actually see the process
- Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for download to update progress so user can actually see the progress