# Why do toast notifications die if delayed?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm not sure this is the exact cause of my problem but I'll explain the 2 symptoms I noticed:

1. If I put a break point on a Toast.makeText(..).show(), step over, then wait a few seconds before running, the toast will never appear.
2. I have a location callback that tries to show a toast, but it never appears. Maybe I'm doing something else wrong, this is the line in question [in my open source distress signal app](http://code.google.com/p/emergencybutton/source/browse/trunk/src/com/emergency/button/Emergency.java?r=7#48).

Any help or pointers would be appreciated,

--uber

Comment: Why are you passing in the context to the method and then using context.getApplicationContext()?  Also, generally people use the keyword "this" when referring to the base class instead of the class name like you are doing.  I'm not sure if there is a distinct difference there causing you problems.

Comment: getApplicationContext was one of my attempst to fix the issue. It still doesn't work if I just use the context. The reason behind not using "this" is because it's a static method that doesn't require instantiation (there is no "this").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. I guess my callback was running in the UI thread and right after the toast came an HTTP post and a text message, so the UI thread was blocking on itself and not processing the toast. My solution was putting all the heavy work in a separate thread as suggested at [Toast Immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747850/toast-immediately) and elaborated here http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#threading so after I did this everything works magically. There was no problem with the "context" at all.

Concerning the oddity of 2 toasts working and 1 not, I think the maketext(...).show() somehow processes part of the UI toast queue and may cause a toast to appear.

Comment: exactly. when you put the breakpoint, it stalls the UI thread so it can't immediately show the toast message. by the time let it run again, the toast msg timeout has expired so it doesn't show any longer

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.getApplicationContext()` bit of the source line you linked. The application context isn't attached to a `Window`, so your Toast can't actually appear. Use an `Activity` context instead and it'll work fine.

Comment: And re your first question, Toast can only show for one of 2 preset durations which are presumably measured w.r.t. system time rather than thread elapsed time.

Comment: I removed the .getApplicationContext() bit and that same piece of code still doesn't toast. I noticed there's another bug that causes that part to run twice, maybe that somehow affects it. I'll check again.

Comment: Update: It's strange. If I put 2 toasts there one right after the other, the second one does work. One toast alone doesn't do anything. Wtf android? (btw there's no bug concerning running twice - that's just eclipse if you hit F8 on a breakpoint that spans multiple lines, it breaks on each line again (although it appears as only 1 breakpoint on 1 line).

Comment: toast doesn't need an activity context. you can show a toast message from a service or receiver as well. but yes, there's nothing added using the application context.

Comment: Seems you're right... the Toast view doesn't belong to your process at all, and therefore doesn't need to attach to your Window. Mea culpa.